# Get X, Y, Z position from 4 spheres

Tags: c#, gps, trilateration

I have 4 RFID devices that tell me the distance to a 5th device. These distances fluctuate based on interference etc. but what's the most efficient way to get the X, Y, Z position of the 5th device, knowing the positions of the other 4? I guess I'm after a C# trilateration function?

The data feed below show the fixed device IDs (621a,b,c,d) and the distance in cm from the 5th device (322, 317 etc) over time.

[image: Position Data]